# Flutter Setting Environment

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

i would like to ask regarding installation of flutter on Windows 10.

How can i solve this problem using flutter doctor, it said that I need to install flutter and dart plugin in android studio, I did install the plugin but when I check using flutter doctor it keep said that I need to install those plugin on my android studio, i tried to restart my Android studio even my PC but this is still happen.

[This is the screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTTp0.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar how its done in windows but after installing the plugin, try to close and open a fresh new cmd-terminal and check again

Comment: I had same problem but there is no problem run and debug flutter app,it's just a bug i think,most of the user have same problem new android studio updates,try create a project and run the app@Walkman

Answer (score 0):

It worked both mac os , Windows 10,7
1.remove plugins flutter and dart first
2.restart android studios , then re-install both above plugins again ..
3.if still not problem solves - uninstall (note- only last option )

Answer (score 0):

Delete .AndroidStudio folder in C:\User[your name] and reinstall android studio and let it to download all requirements then install Flutter plugin.
it might be solve your problem